# 3 DIVs same height. Shrink leftmost width and all heights with window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to do this with CSS only.

Have a Canvas on the left side that I want to shrink both width and height as the window is resized. Want the center and right divs to shrink in height to match the canvas. Don't want center and right divs to move under the canvas.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
      <canvas id="draw" width="250" height="300"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="center" class="center"></div>
  <div id="right" class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrx6zk27/

Any help would be appreciated. Expecting I will probably need JavaScript to align the heights, but want to reduce JavaScript as much as possible.

Update: Fiddle using table layout (doesn't work): https://jsfiddle.net/mrx6zk27/2/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because three column layouts can be found with a host of solutions just by searching SO or Google. Flexible height and width are fundamentals of CSS.

Comment: There are many solutions, but none I found worked partially because Google tends to favor older pages over newer ones. The width and height properties of Canvas are special in that they maintain a height / width ratio like an image would. Couldn't get the Canvas height shrink with the width, and then allowing overflow divs to also shrink accordingly. Pangloss' solution worked for me.

Comment: In Google Search, click on "Search Tools" and select any date range you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sugest to use `flexbox`, It's required to update the center and right divs in the markup slightly for this solution. See the code snippet and demo as follows.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrx6zk27/1/)**

```js
var c = document.getElementById("draw");
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 300);
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.font = "bold 40pt Arial";
ctx.fillText("CANVAS", 10, 100);

tmp = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    tmp += "<p>" + i + "</p>";
}

document.getElementById("center").innerHTML = tmp;
document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = tmp;
```

```css
.container {
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
}
.container > div {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 0;
}
.left {
    max-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
}
.left canvas {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.center {
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: blue;
}
.right {
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: green;
}
.scroll {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <canvas id="draw" width="250" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="center"><div id="center" class="scroll"></div></div>
    <div class="right"><div id="right" class="scroll"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if this is what you want, but I think you use display:table.

```
<div id="container" style="display: table; width:100%;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; background-color: red; width:-100%; height:200px"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; background-color: blue; width:300px;"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; background-color: green; width: 300px;">     </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8mpx1kok/2/

Comment: Had tried something like that originally, but didn't work with canvas height shrinking or overflow-y scroll divs. Added new fiddle to question to show.